# chromium download tray

Tags: upgrade, permissions

Chromium moved the download tray from the bottom of the screen to the right side of the address bar. How to bring back old tray?

Previously I did the following below:

To restore the old Chrome download tray, I typed “chrome://flags” in the address bar and typed ‘download bubble’ in the search bar and Chromium showed two flags named ‘Enable download bubble’ and ‘Enable download bubble V2’.

On the drop-down menu that appeared on the right side of the ‘Enable download bubble’, I changed the value from ‘Default’ to ‘Disabled’. It worked.

Now the download bubble is unavailable. Can anyone help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGEzt.png)